# Can ceiling be left open if hidden by cabinets?

Tags: drywall, soffit

My contractor is not going to drywall portion of kitchen ceiling as it will be covered by 9" cabinet crown molding.  There are mechanicals (water supply lines, HVAC, and drain pipes) in the way.  The area behind is unfinished dead space around a curved staircase.  I worry about mice getting into kitchen as I have a wooded backyard. I also wonder if there is some type of fire barrier safety issue. Is this a good solution? Is this acceptable and compliant?[image]

Comment: The big issue with mice (and many other critters) is entry into the house. Once they are inside, they **will** find their way to the kitchen. So I'd worry more about holes (even just an inch or two) on the outer walls and less about gaps inside the house between rooms, etc.

Comment: Are you concerned about hearing the tub drain or the toilet flush in the kitchen? At a minimum, I'd ask that the area be filled with insulation for sound damping. You might double-check with your AHJ as to whether it's a requirement for fire suppression.